# How to include the 'current-menu-ancestor' class on a custom post type menu in Wordpress?

Tags: menus

I need the Wordpress menu to include the 'current-menu-ancestor' class to reflect that site is currently in the recipe section. Supposing I have a recipe custom post type. I have the following code in my functions.php but it's not working:

```
function add_active_item_classes($classes = array(), $menu_item = false){

if ( get_post_type() == 'recipe' && $menu_item->title == 'Recipes') {
$classes[] = 'current-menu-ancestor';

return $menuclasses;
}
}
```

Also I don't know what filter hooks I will use to have this effect? Thanks for your suggestion and assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the final working code:

```
<?php
function additional_active_item_classes($classes = array(), $menu_item = false){
global $wp_query;

if(in_array('current-menu-item', $menu_item->classes)){
    $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
}

if ( $menu_item->post_name == 'product' && is_post_type_archive('product') ) {
    $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
}

if ( $menu_item->post_name == 'product' && is_singular('product') ) {
    $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
}


return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'additional_active_item_classes', 10, 2 );

?>
```

Comment: WTF is this? It doesn't add the `current-menu-ancestor` class and you declare `global $wp_query` but never use it. Please figure out what the hell you are doing before trying to help others.

Answer (score 0):

This code add class 'current-menu-ancestor' to parent item menu of your child CPT or custom taxonomy or default single post, in case you do not have a nested menu structure in the admin panel - only if you have 'level 0' menu. For example - if you have Page Product, which display products grid and you go to the single product - WP will not see the parent menu item. The code below improve this:

```
function additional_active_item_classes( $classes = array(), $menu_item = false ) {
    // custom taxonomy
    if ( $menu_item->title == 'Custom Tax Name Page' && is_tax('custom_tax') ) {
        $classes[] = 'current-menu-ancestor';
    }
    // custom post type single
    if ( $menu_item->title == 'Custom Post Type Page' && is_singular('products') ) {
        $classes[] = 'current-menu-ancestor';
    }
    // blog post single
    if ( $menu_item->title == 'Blog Page' && is_singular('post') ) {
        $classes[] = 'current-menu-ancestor';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'additional_active_item_classes', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?